# PHP POST variable not recieving data from AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

I'm trying to send the clicked id of an element to my PHP file, using AJAX, so that my SQL statement can select the appropriate data. Everything seems to be working accept that my `$_POST` variables remain undefined.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.productsForm').submit(createEntry);
    $('.clickProducts').bind('click touchend', refreshEntries);
});

function refreshEntries() {
    //Get the id number of the clicked element.
    var clicked_id = (this.id);
    var cigar_id = clicked_id.toString();
    var display = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/mobile-select.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { product_id : cigar_id
        },
        success: function(json){
            //I'm attempting to loop through the JSON object and create product arrays for each cigar.
            $.each(json, function(key, value){
               $.each(value, function(x, y){
                    display += '<tr><td>'+ x + '</td><td>' + y +'</td></tr>';
                });
            });

        console.log(display);


        }
    })
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    include("connect-db.php");

    // Post remains undefined for some reason. ????
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    $select_sql = "SELECT product_name, current_inventory, price FROM products WHERE product_id = '$product_id' ";

    $result = $conn->query($select_sql);

    $data = array();

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $r;
    }

    $conn->close();

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request /response in your browser's console? Are there any errors there?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I don't fully understand why, but removing "contentType: "application/json" " from my .ajax function did the trick. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

You're sending a json object, so you'll need to read the raw data.

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($request_body, true);
```

$post will contain the object you are passing in an array.

Also be careful on passing product_id directly to the SQL statement. Opens you to SQL attacks.